# Passing nested lists to sklearn split function

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I've recently started to learn Python for machine learning purposes and I ran into a problem. I am inputting data from .csv file using Pandas and transforming the row values to arrays of numbers. I need to pass those arrays into sklearn function. My code is here:

```
# Imports
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sklearn
import os
import seaborn as seabornInstance
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import preprocessing


# Dataset input
dirname = os.path.dirname(__file__)
filename = os.path.join(dirname, 'Datasets', 'car.data')
data = pd.read_csv(filename)
label_encoder = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()

# Transforming text
x = [label_encoder.fit_transform(list(data[col])) for col in data.columns if col!='class']
y = [label_encoder.fit_transform(list(data['class']))]
```

The Problem now arrives here. I need to access the nested arrays inside of x and put them in my sklearn function, because fitting 'x' in there will throw an error:

> ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of
>   samples: [6, 1]

```
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split(x[0], y[0], test_size = 0.08)
```

Is there a way to pass all of the nested arrays as x and not the whole x without writing x[0],x[1],..? I do not think it would work using a loop, since I need to pass it all at once, or am I wrong?

EDIT: The data I am importing are not numeric (string), that is why I am using a label_encoder to transform those values into numeric ones for use in KNN algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're making it unnecessarily complicated. You shouldn't label encode your `x` variable either. As the name says, it's for the `label`, not the predictor variable. For your `x` variable, you should use these lines:

```py
x = df.loc[:, [i for i in df.columns if i != 'class']]
# or
x = df.drop('class', axis=1)
```

And for your `y` variable:

```py
y = label_encoder.fit_transform(df['class'])
```

Comment: Thank you but the reason why I encoded my ```x``` was because there are string values in my csv and I wanted to convert them to numeric values for KNN, forgot to mention that in my post, is there a way around it?

Comment: It's hard to tell without a look into your data but the function you're looking for is `from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder`

Comment: Yes, sorry, forgot to mention it. This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much.